# Que signifie "à la rémoule" ?

Tags: sens, locutions

Dans le passage suivant, Céline se sert de la locution ***à la rémoule*** pour décrire une pièce jouée au piano :

"Ainsi de suite jusqu'au dîner, des fois, trois quatre heures à la file!... à la bagotte à la galope! d'octaves en *ré!... ding! dim! brim!* à la moustille!... **à la rémoule!** cinq! trois! quatre! *Dzim!*..."

Savez-vous, s'il vous plaît, que signifie ***à la rémoule*** ? s'agit-il d'une forme du verbe "remoudre" ou d'une apocope de "rémoulade" ?

Answer (score 5):

Il n'existe pas de nom *rémoule*, on peut penser que c'est une création à partir du verbe *[rémouler](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/r%C3%A9mouler)* qui veut dire aiguiser/affuter. *À la rémoule* pourrait alors être compris comme  *à l’affûtage*, l’affûtage servant à rendre un objet tranchant plus performant. Ici le pianiste rejouant les passages, il en est plus performant. Cet interprétation m'est aussi suggérée par « pointu » et « tout reprend à la va vite » dans le paragraphe juste précédent.

Le choix des mots dans tout le passage est fait en fonction du rythme (on pourrait presque battre la mesure) et des sonorités, allitérations, répétitions...

Par le choix des mots l'auteur veut donner un sentiment de rapidité et de légèreté :

- à la bagote (le mot est une création à partir de bagotter (vieux terme argotique qui veut dire se dépêcher),
- à la galope (création à partir de galoper),
- à la moustille (formé à partir de moustiller qui signifie pétiller),
- à la rémoule pour la répétition.

Et bien sûr on a les allitérations.

---

Note : je ne pense pas que la description soit celle de la pièce jouée au piano mais la description de la façon dont joue Borokrom qui est au piano.

Answer (score 1):

Spontanément, ayant vu œuvrer des rémouleurs, "la rémoule" évoque la pierre à aiguiser qui tourne sans cesse grâce à une pédale que l'on actionne du pied, en appuyant régulièrement et énergiquement. L'action de la pierre sur les outils générant bien sûr un grincement métallique continu passablement pénible.

Je pense que c'est une image que "à la rémoule" pourrait avoir évoquer assez naturellement à l'époque: à la fois le mouvement répétitif, le pied qui bat régulièrement, le grincement métallique.

Answer (score 0):

La rémoulade est une sauce.

> ([TLFi](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/r%C3%A9moulade)) ART CULIN. Sauce piquante consistant en une mayonnaise fortement moutardée agrémentée d'ail et de fines herbes, qui sert à assaisonner certains légumes crus, les viandes ou les poissons.

La « rémoule » ne semble correspondre à rien en dehors d'une apocope de « rémoulade » dans le langage de Céline. S'il s'agissait du verbe « remouler », en supposant le substantif « remoule » improvisé par Céline, il y aurait un accent aigu en trop et difficile à expliquer.
On s'aperçoit que « à la rémoulade » se trouve trois fois dans le livre, les deux à la p. 134, et cela, directement avant l'unique occurrence de « rémoule » qui est à la p. 134. De plus les occurrence de ce terme et de son apocope sont connectées à la description d'un art musical, l'art musical de foire ou apparenté.

- 1/ […] de cette **bonne rémoulade foraine**, de cette bonne gigoterie pianotée. […]
- 2/  […]des heures et des heures je l'ai vu comme ça cabrioler de tierces en quartes et brèves pointées... au sursaut... **à la rémoulade**... jamais ni distrait, ni soupir... jamais un seul mot... […]
- 3/ […] repris, ratatouillé, dégobillé par toutes les mécaniques du monde, par tous les jazz des continents !... par les bougnoules d'un peu partout !... **à la rémoulade cafouillette**... Mais à l'époque dont je vous cause, c'était encore de la primeur... la salade jamais entendue...
- 4/ à la bagotte à la galope ! d'octaves en ré !... ding ! dim ! brim ! à la moustille !... **à la rémoule** ! cinq ! trois ! quatre ! Dzim !... une pluie de dièses !... de triste à liesse ! et rigodon !... Facilement il prenait sa livre comme ça à l'estome le Boro en ses trois quatre heures de crincrin !...

*Guignol's Band, p. 134*

> J'en ai vendu par la suite avec le
> Boro, après bien des péripéties, de cette bonne **rémoulade** foraine, de
> cette bonne gigoterie pianotée... Fallait entendre notre « à trois
> mains »... Je faisais la « basse du mutilé » ma partie d'octaves... j'ai eu le
> temps de bien y réfléchir aux façons du charme... par la suite, les jours...
> Il faut que ça tourne ! c'est le grand secret... jamais de ralenti jamais de
> cesse ! que ça s'égrène comme des secondes, chacune avec sa petite
> malice, sa petite âme dansante, pressée, mais nom de Dieu l'autre qui la
> pousse !... d'un trille te la bouscule... sursaute !... que ça vous tinte plein
> les soucis... vous triche le temps, vous tille la peine, lutine, mutine, tinte
> aux soucis, et ptemm ! ptemm ! vous la tourbillonne !... vous l'emporte...
> constante à galope ! notes en notes !... et puis l'arpège ! encore un
> trille !... frais mutin l'air anglais dévale !... rigodon grêle !... pédale
> tonne ! jamais ne dédit... ne soupire... pose !... C'est ça le triste quand
> on y songe !... toute cette gentillesse éperdue, toujours filante, de notes
> en notes... Fallait le voir en train le Boro ! ce brio d'artiste ! sur la
> question du bastringue... clinquant... mais cadencé volage !... et le
> répertoire !... la mémoire !... les variations à l'infini !... Lui plutôt
> loursingue de nature et franchement brutal et pénible avec sa manie
> d'explosifs, il devenait là tout voltigeur, tout cascadeur, tout lutin !... Il
> avait l'esprit dans les doigts... Des mains de fées !... des papillons sur les
> ivoires... Il virevolait aux harmonies !... piquait l'une et l'autre à
> 133
> l'envol !... songes et toquades !... guirlandes... détours... fredaines
> prestes... Possédé !... pas autre chose à dire !... par vingt petits diables
> dans les doigts !... Jamais mauvaise humeur ou las ! des heures et des
> heures je l'ai vu comme ça cabrioler de tierces en quartes et brèves
> pointées... au sursaut... à la **rémoulade**... jamais ni distrait, ni soupir...
> jamais un seul mot... « C'est assez ! »... toujours fringant... gai
> hypnotique dodelinant de sa grosse bouille, cinq, trois doigts, pile !...
> retombe tonique !... Un coup d'accords ! dièse ! C'est gagné !... Le
> charme enchaîne !... C'est la rengaine digne et ficelle... Jamais venue...
> jamais finie !... tapée, moulue, mouchée, retorse... coquine aux nerfs et
> cavalière et qui s'impose à tous les cœurs !... et là pour ça !... et pas
> d'histoire !... et drope lyrique ! et pompe pédale !... et que c'est du casse-
> sentiments !... à la tirette !... à l'escamote !... d'un doigt sur l'autre !...
> fonce aigrelette... et file et file !... bouzille au fa !... la !... si !... do ! do !
> dérape... requinque !... barre à bout de dièses !... La revoilà !... jamais
> n'expire !... C'est une affaire !... riguedondonne !... Le monde halète !...
> pâme... se rend !... farceur d'ivoires !... façon friponne !... rêche et
> câline !... brute et toucheuse ! à dig ! dong !... débraille notes !... sorcière
> des mains ! conquiert et sonne !... digue dondonne !... emporte tout !...
> le monde vogue !... tout ensorcelle, dissolve, papille ! parpille aux
> ondes ! dig ! dig ! dong ! ne flanchez pas !... Tenez au si ! dièse ! dièse !
> dièse !... dum !...
> Le truc a fait fureur depuis, mille fois repris, ratatouillé, dégobillé par
> toutes les mécaniques du monde, par tous les jazz des continents !... par
> les bougnoules d'un peu partout !... à la **rémoulade** cafouillette... Mais à
> l'époque dont je vous cause, c'était encore de la primeur... la salade
> jamais entendue... le genre à froid sentimental, le sautillé marrant
> message des temps tout voyous à venir !... tintant coquin au coin des
> squares... au bord des « pubs », l'aigrelet, nerveux rigodon... à la pédale
> et hop là sec !... le baise à froid, le bien meilleur !... la mousse et
> poivre !... que tout le monde voulait plus autre chose ! cynique, capital
> 134
> et pressé !... à poil les notes !... le cœur à poil !... ding !... dong !... ding !...
> gambade à quatre, cinq, trois doigts pile !

*Guignol's Band, p. 137*

> Ainsi de suite jusqu'au dîner, des fois, trois quatre heures à la file !... à
> la bagotte à la galope ! d'octaves en ré !... ding ! dim ! brim ! à la
> moustille !... à la **rémoule** ! cinq ! trois ! quatre ! Dzim !... une pluie de
> dièses !... de triste à liesse ! et rigodon !...
> Facilement il prenait sa livre comme ça à l'estome le Boro en ses trois
> quatre heures de crincrin !... d'un pub à l'autre, toujours son genre,
> « passez la monnaie ! »... le coup d'arrêt... la reprise. C'était du
> clinquant, de la suée, mais pas encore si brutal que son numéro dehors...
> il aimait pas l'intérieur, il préférait beaucoup la rue, la vie au grand air !

À mon avis, il est difficile d'affirmer la validité d'une interprétation ; la suivante semble pouvoir se tenir, mais il me semble qu'une autre pourrait facilement la remplacer, et il n'est pas sûr non plus qu'il ne s'agisse pas chez l'auteur de la simple impression  de ne voir dans tout cela que cuisine avec les notions de malhonnêteté et de mauvaise qualité que cela peut impliquer (p. 137 : du clinquant (généralement superficiel ou factice et parfois de mauvais goût.)).
Au « 1/ », « rémoulade » se comprend assez bien comme « ambience » : « de cette bonne ambience foraine, de cette bonne gigoterie pianotée ». On peut comprendre que l'auteur associe à cette ambience une musique de piano.
Au « 2/ », le terme semble prendre une autre dimension, plutôt, la dimension finale du terme prendrait consistence. La majorité des termes contribuent à montrer l'inexorable succession des notes, des actes et sentiments qui les produisent, l'exécution parfaitement mécanique de cette exhibition (plus loin : « repris, … par toutes ls mécaniques du monde »). « À la rémoulade » peut donc prétendre rimer avec l'art culinaire, lequel ne connait de céleri que s'il est à la rémoulade ; tout cet apparat musical est présenté comme étant de rigueur.
Au « 3/ », le diminutif péjoratif de « à la rémoulade cafouillette » (due à céline, ce mot n'existe pas) n'ajoute qu'un détail.
Au « 4/ », l'apocope ne semble rien ajouter de particulier, sauf peut-être en tant que note qui confère le rechignement de l'auteur à utiliser le mot une quatrième fois, si ce n'est pas une note qui se veut la concrétisation d'un nouveau concept péjoratif que ce qui a précédé révèlerait, une interprétation peut-être plus probable encore.